# страница благодарности

Tags: php, форма, связи

Всем привет такая проблема нашёл классный скрипт формы обратной связи вот он:

стили

```
<style>
#feedback-form { /* вся форма */
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
#feedback-form label { /* наименование полей */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
#feedback-form .w100 { /* поля */
  float: right;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1.5%;
}
#feedback-form .border { /* граница полей */
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #C0C0C0 #D9D9D9 #D9D9D9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #abd9f1 #bfe3f7 #bfe3f7;
}
#feedback-form .border:hover {
  border-color: #7eb4ea #97cdea #97cdea;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* убрать при фокусе первоначальный текст поля */
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
#feedback-form .border:not(:focus):not(:hover):valid { /* правильно заполненные поля */
  opacity: .8;
}
#submitFF { /* кнопка "Отправить" */
  padding: 2%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) inset;
  background: #669acc;
  color: #fff;
}
#feedback-form br {
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
#submitFF:hover {
  background: #5c90c2;
}
#submitFF:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
</style>
```

html код и скрипт

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form">
<label for="nameFF">Имя:</label>
<input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" required placeholder="например, Иван Иванович Иванов" x-autocompletetype="name" class="w100 border">
<label for="contactFF">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" required placeholder="например, ivan@yandex.ru" x-autocompletetype="email" class="w100 border">
<label for="fileFF">Прикрепить файл:</label>
<input type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="w100">
<label for="messageFF">Сообщение:</label>
<textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class="w100 border"></textarea>
<br>
<input value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(), f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
      if (http.responseText.indexOf(f.nameFF.value) == 0) { // очистить поле сообщения, если в ответе первым словом будет имя отправителя
        f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value');
        f.messageFF.value='';
      }
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
  http.send(new FormData(f));
}, false);
</script>
```

файл contacts.php

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
  $to = "name@yandex.ru"; // поменять на свой электронный адрес
  $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$from."\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }
   $message.="
--$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

Задача простая, нужно чтобы после отправки формы не всплывало окно мол сообщение отправлено как здесь [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а чтобы перекидывало на страницу какую либо например blago.html помогите пожалуйста php и js начинаю только сейчас изучать, заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(), f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      window.location = "blago.html";
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
  http.send(new FormData(f));
}, false);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, самые лучшие советы на этом форуме